# <?php comments_template('', true); ?> doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to include comments on my *single.php*. If it is needed to add extra code or additional file please inform me. Thanks in advance. This is my *single.php* file:

```
<div class="col-m-9">
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> ">
            <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-thumb'); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php comments_template('', true); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>404 not found:</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

But it's not showing the commenting option. I have tried with for a long time. 
I have not added *comments.php*.

Comment: Following link may help you. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a file called `comments.php` in your theme folder for the template to render.  Or you can specify a file name and pass it as the first parameter for the function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/